# passing jquery object with data to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you a pass jQuery object with data to a function?

For example i have the following object:

```
var el = $('#myelement').data('test1','yay1')
                    .data('test2','yay2')
                    .data('test3','yay3');
```

and additional functions to process object data:

```
jQuery.fn.allData = function() {
    var intID = jQuery.data(this.get(0));
    return(jQuery.cache[intID]);
};

function checkIt (myobj){
  $.each($(myobj).allData(), function(key, value) {
    alert(key + "=" + value);
  });
}
```

Then I call the `checkIt` function and pass `myelement`:

```
checkIt(el);
```

But something goes wrong:
**TypeError: obj is undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `allData` function isn't necessary to do what you want.
You could do something like this:

```
function checkIt (myobj){
    $.each(myobj.data(), function(key, value) {
        alert(key + "=" + value);
    });
}
```

`myobj.data()` will return an object with all the data assigned to the element.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `jQuery.data()` on an element, it returns all the data attached to that element, so `jQuery.fn.allData` is redundant. Rewrite your `checkIt` function so it reads something like this:

```
function checkIt(myObj) {
  $.each($.data($(myObj)), function(key, value) {
    alert(key + "=" + value);
  })
}
```